# bash: how to execute a line from a file?

Tags: bash, command-line

I guess this is easy but I couldn't figure it out. Basically I have a command history file and I'd like to grep a line and execute it. How do I do it?

For example: in the file command.txt file, there is:

wc -l *txt| awk '{OFS="\t";print $2,$1}' > test.log

Suppose the above line is the last line, what I want to do is something like this

```
tail -1 command.txt | "execute"
```

I tried to use

```
tail -1 command.txt | echo
```

but no luck.

Can someone tell me how to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: question for you: do you know about the "history" command? It keeps track of the commands that you've recently used and executing a command from it is very easy.

Comment: @theSilentOne yes, I know history. But I want to have a more general mechanism in case I run a command a while ago and just want to rerun it

Comment: You can set the history limit to be nearly infinite but I can see the usefulness of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use command substitution

```
bash -c "$(tail -1 command.txt)"
```

Comment: Cool you find a good answer. If @BroSlow is the answer, how do you think about rephrasing a bit your question, especially the title and the intro? This answer works, but it seems to answer a slightly different question. Just thinking about people who will search.

Answer (score 4):

You can load an arbitrary file into your shell's history list with

```
history -r command.txt
```

at which point you can use all the normal history expansion commands to find the command you wish to execute. For example, after executing the above command, the last line in the file would be available to run with

```
!!
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
echo "ls -l" | xargs sh -c
```

This answer addresses just the execution part. It assumes you have a method to extract the line you want from the file, perhaps a loop on each line. Each line of the file would be the argument for `echo`.

Comment: thanks! I tried to use xargs bash -c with tail but something about wrapping the command line isn't quite right...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval`.

```
eval "$(tail -n 1 ~/.bash_history)"
```

or if you want it to execute some other line:

```
while read -r; do
    if some condition; then
        eval "$REPLY"
    fi
done < ~/.bash_history
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are expecting to execute the line several times in this bash session, consider adding it to an alias:

```
alias aa="$(tail -1 command.txt)"
```

then you could use `aa<CR>` to execute the content from the line.